# How to store extra attributes via kwargs in Python dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I would like to have a Python dataclass with optional attributes that could be passed during initialization via `kwargs`.

Something like

```py
@dataclass(allow_kwargs_init=True)
class Person:
    name: str
    birth_year: int

me = Person("myself", 1910)
you = Person("yourself", 2020, company="StackOverflow")

print(me)  # Person(name='myself', birth_year=1910)
print(you)  # Person(name='yourself', birth_year=2020, company='StackOverflow')
```

Would there be a way without re-writing the `__init__` function and `__repr__` functions?

Comment: The `repr` is created during class creation and only checks fields known at that time, so I don't see how you could get that easily, unfortunately. A mix of the linked dupe's proposal would probably look best, where you have a `extra: field(default_factory=dict)` field and a `@classmethod` that fills this extra dict with every non-native kwarg.

Comment: @Arne  I also had this in mind, actually :) ... but not easy. Anyway, I have solved my issue by just adding the extra field in the attributes since I actually know its name :)